# Vue list, how to check if a user is already added

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vuetify's combobox to search for users and build a list.

```
         <v-combobox
            v-model="event.user"
            :items="usersData"
            label="Search speaker list"
            :search-input.sync="searchUser"
            return-object
            item-value="id"
            item-text="name"
          >
          </v-combobox>
```

I have an addSpeaker method. My question is what is the best way to check if a user has already been added and ideally prevent them from being added again?

```
addSpeaker () {
  const newSpeaker = {
    id: Date.now(),
    name: this.event.user.name,
    company: this.event.user.company,
    jobTitle: this.event.user.jobTitle
  }
  this.speakers.push(newSpeaker)
  this.event.user = ''
}
```

Comment: "best way to check if a user has already been added" -- added to `this.speakers`? It's not entirely clear from your question if that's what you mean, maybe you could edit to be clearer.

Comment: Okay will do. What I mean is would I use a filter to check the ID, I'm just not sure what I'm looking for here

Answer (score 2):

If `this.speakers` is an Array, as is implied by your use of `this.speakers.push`, the only way to check if a user is already in the array is to iterate over the whole array and compare the "nominated" speaker with each element.

On average, you will make `n/2` comparisons for an array with `n` elements, and at worst `n` comparisons. This may be acceptable if your array never gets too large. How many speakers will there be? 10? 100? 10,000? The cost of 10 comparisons is probably fine.

With an Array you can use the [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to check:

```js
var speakers = [];

speakers.push({id: "speakerId-17", last: "Smith", first: "John", jobTitle: "Guru", company: "Acme Corp"});
speakers.push({id: "speakerId-8", last: "Jones", first: "Laura", jobTitle: "Guru", company: "Ajax Corp"});

if (speakers.find(o => o.id==='speakerId-8')) {
    console.log("speakerId-8 is already in speakers list, Don't add");
}
else {
    console.log("Add speakerId-8");
}

if (speakers.find(o => o.id==='speakerId-11')) {
    console.log("speakerId-11 is already in speakers list, Don't add");
}
else {
    console.log("Add speakerId-11");
}
```

This would make your code something like this:

```js
if (! this.speakers.find(o => o.id === newSpeaker.id)) {
    this.speakers.push(newSpeaker)
}
```

The alternative is to somehow index the speakers already added, and a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) would be useful for this.

You would make `this.speakers` a Map instead of an Array, and add a speaker to the map when chosen using the `.set()` method, and can check if they are already in the map with `.has()`.

A simple example, using hard-coded elements — you would of course be using your variables:

```js
var /*this.*/speakers = new Map();
// ...
if (! speakers.has('speakerId-17')) {
    speakers.set('speakerId-17',
                 { 'last':'Smith',
                   'first':'John',
                   'jobTitle':'Guru',
                   'company':'Acme Corp' }
                );
}
```